# php -v command not found but getting phpinfo();

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php7

I have installed php and in cmd on doing

> sudo /usr/local/php7/bin/php -v

it shows the php version but on doing

> php -v

its not showing getting us command not my phpinfo() also workd

how can I point to get php version on simply doing **php -v**

I am using centos7

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your $PATH in .bashrc or .zshrc (if you use zsh)?
It looks like just a problem of PATH configuration.
You can check it with `env $PATH`

Comment: Is there a way to point with the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` modify your PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

or if you have to override the default version of PHP on Centos (this gives "priority" to PHP and other executables in `/usr/local/bin`)

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

save and exit, then:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

It should work and `php -v` doesn't require you to specify the full path

Further reading:

https://www.tecmint.com/set-path-variable-linux-permanently/

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214202148-How-do-I-change-the-PHP-version-my-shell-uses-

I assume you are beginning your geeky adventures with Linux, if the answer is yes, take also a look at:

https://vegibit.com/vi-editor-tutorial-for-beginners/

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/

Hope this solution can help you ;-)

Comment: Thank You, It also fixed my composer issue.

Answer (score 0):

With my local ubuntu 18.04 I changed from PHP 7.1 to 7.2

```
  vi ~/.bashrc
  echo "PATH=/usr/bin/php7.2:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
  echo "alias php='/usr/bin/php7.2'" >> ~/.bashrc
  source ~/.bashrc

  sudo a2dismod php7.1
  sudo a2enmod php7.2
  sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
  sudo service apache2 restart
```